# Using an average of 10 rows for multiple cells, then moving to the average to the next 10 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large column of data where every 10 rows is a different set. 
What I would like to do is get the average of those 10 rows, and then subtract that from every individual measured value.

Then it moves to the next 10, takes the average of those, and subtracts it from the 10 data points that yielded the new average.

I've tried using MOD and plenty of formulas and dragging out some kind of formula but Excel's pattern recognition is not working at all in this case.

Example of what I'm trying to do using 3 values instead of 10

The output I want takes the average of the first 3 values ((1+2+3)/3=2), then subtracts it from those 3 values and outputs it as the result. (1-2=-1, 2-2=0, 3-2=1). Then it repeats the same thing with the next 3 and the results from the previous 3 do not affect it.

Values________Average_______Result

1|__________________________-1

2|______________2     __________           0

3|__________________________1

2|__________________________-2

5|______________4 __________ 1

5|___________________________1

2|___________________________-1

5|_____________3_____________2

2|___________________________-1

(I'm so sorry about the awful table)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data and doing every three:

```
=A2-AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3)*3+2):INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3)*3+4))
```

To change to 10 change the each `/3` to `/10` and `*3` to `*10` this is the interval.  You will also need to change the `+2` to the first row of data and the `+4` to `+11` or `+[the interval]-1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like Scott's answer better, but since I had worked it out while he was typing, I'll add my solution as well.

I'm using the `INDIRECT` function to build the range reference and calculating the range for the `AVERAGE` by using `MOD` on the `ROW` function.

Basically you're looking to average over the first ten rows, so you need the range `A1:A10`, then `A11:20`, and so on. In order to calculate the beginning row, take your current `ROW()` and subtract the `MOD 10` of its previous row: `ROW()-MOD(ROW()-1,10)`. The last row of the group just adds 9 rows: `ROW()-MOD(ROW()-1,10)+9`.

Everything in Column B uses the formula:

`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-MOD(ROW()-1,10)&":A"&ROW()-MOD(ROW()-1,10)+9))`

[image]

Comment: I also tested this one and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!